# CSS, knockout.js : how to dynamically assign id to checkbox with foreach data-bind

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I have this code where I am using knockout.js `foreach` binding with checkboxes styled using images in css classes.

how can I dynamically assign id to each checkbox separately and associate the label to that dynamic checkbox id.

Can anyone help me resolve this?

```css
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox1 {
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox1 + label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url(../images/img_sprite.png) no-repeat -14px -78px;
}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox1:checked + label {
  background: url(../images/img_sprite.png) no-repeat -47px -78px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Activity" data-bind="click: showActivity" />
  <div data-bind="if: showActivityMenu">
    <div data-bind="foreach:activity">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value=" " data-bind="checkedValue: name, checked:$parent.selectedActivity" class="css-checkbox1" />
      <label for="checkbox1" data-bind="text:name"></label>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button data-bind="click:collectActivity">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="ifnot: showActivityMenu">
    <span class="inner" data-bind="text:selectedActivity"> </span> 
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  function AAsearchViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.showActivityMenu = ko.observable(false);
    self.activity = ko.observableArray([{
      name: 'Yoga',
      val: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Pilates',
      val: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Kickboxing',
      val: 3
    }]);
    self.selectedActivity = ko.observableArray(['Pilates']);
    self.showActivity = function() {
      self.showActivityMenu(true);
    };
    self.collectActivity = function() {
      self.showActivityMenu(false);
    };
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new AAsearchViewModel());
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: This is ***so very basic***. `id` ***must be unique as per-document.***

Comment: That's not the *relevant* code you've posted: it's way, way more...

Comment: @connexo: I agree. Fairly basic. Am a total newbie to html/css/JS/KO. This is my first attempt at a webpage. I just couldn't figure out how to dynamically set the ids. Viktor has helped me understand how to do it. Thanks for looking up the question.

Comment: You can also "change the *past*", and improve (i.e. edit) this question so it's easier for others with the same issue to understand.

Comment: @Jereon: edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your html become invalid because all checkboxes got the same id, and the labels got the same `for` attribute so only the first checkbox will be checked when you click on any of the labels.

The solution will be to generate unique ids (ex. use `$index()` in the `foreach`):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id: 'checkbox' + $index() }, checkedValue: name, checked:$parent.selectedActivity"  class="css-checkbox1"/>
<label data-bind="text:name, attr: { for: 'checkbox' + $index() }"></label>
```

Here is a [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w6tkcvxh/)

Comment: thanks! your solution solves the second problem perfectly. Would you have any idea on how to resolve the CSS issue of aligning the checkboxes properly? Many thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately I'm not a CSS guy and I cant help for that part.

Comment: Putting each checkbox+label in a div lines them up nicely. https://jsfiddle.net/w6tkcvxh/1/